SQLCODE Function - 942
I am new to plsql and am trying to understand what the code below does. What does the 942 mean and why would someone want to use the code below? Thanks.
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE mostRecent
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
            RAISE;
        END IF;
END;

Just wanting to know what it is doing. The explanations when i google for what they mean do not make sense to me with limited plsql knowledge.

The goal of your procedure is to drop a table. There are two cases when you try to drop a table:

The table exists
The table doesn't exist

If you run the drop table command and the table exists, the table is dropped. However, if you run the drop table command and the table doesn't exist, you will get an ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error. (As demonstrated in this db<>fiddle.)
The procedure you have contains an exception handler that says "if an error occurs, check to see if it's an error code -942, and if it isn't, raise the exception. I.e. it's preventing an error from being raised if the table doesn't already exist. (As demonstrated in this db<>fiddle.)
